# How to define repository.home at startup

Tags: sling, jackrabbit-oak

I'm trying to define a folder for the Tar/Repository files in Sling. However, I can't figure out the right way to set an alternative repository.home folder.

As I understand it the Tar `SegmentNodeStoreService` is supposed to default to a folder under the `{sling.home}` path, set with the `-c` argument. No matter what I try it is always placing the repository folder relative to the folder I'm running start from. The rest of Sling goes in the `sling.home` folder.

For instance, if I'm in

```
~/Development
```

and I run

```
java -jar project/target/sling-app.jar -c /temp
```

The sling bundles, logs, etc will be under /temp, but the sling/repository folder will be put under the `~/Development` folder.

I've tried adding these extra command line arguments too, but they don't help.

```
-Drepository.home=/temp
-Dsling.repository.home=/temp
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a bug and it is now fixed in sling 9

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-6022